# Downloading HTML string into an NSString or Swift String variable in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

> ### Alternative titles
>
> - How to download a web page data in Objective-C on iPhone?
> - How to read entire content of an html resource file into an `NSString *`
> - How to download a web page data in Swift?
> - Saving HTML pages in an NSString

How do you get web page data and put the data into a string?

Something like:

```
NSString *webPageBody = GetWebPageData("www.mysite.com/webpage.html");
```

in the `webPageBody`, I would like to see "html my web page html".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Swift 3.0

```
guard let url = URL(string: "http://www.example.com") else {
    return
}

do {
    let html = try String(contentsOf: url)
}
catch {
    //handle `error` here
}
```

## Swift 2.3

```
guard let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com") else {
    return
}

do {
    let html = try String(contentsOfURL: url)
}
catch {
    //handle `error` here
}
```

### Objective-C

```
NSString *url = @"http://www.example.com";
NSURL *urlRequest = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSError *err = nil;

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:urlRequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];

if(err)
{
    //Handle 
}
```