# iOS - how to read entire content of an html resource file into an NSString *?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to put the content of my `html` resource file into an `NSString` object. Is it possible and advisable to do that? How could it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a web page data in Objective-C on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867002/how-to-download-a-web-page-data-in-objective-c-on-iphone)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Possible? - yes

Advisable? - unless it is an extremely large file, why not?

How? - There is already a method to do it for you in `NSString` - `stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:`.

See the snippet below:

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"foo" ofType: @"html"];
NSString *res = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
```

Comment: Don't forget to check for the error afterwards though. And be sure to save your HTML file as UTF8.

Comment: And to call it foo.html. ;) Just hoped author of a question will read the code instead of blindly copying it.

Comment: haha don't worry I'm not that much a n00b. it worked just fine. thanks!