# How to grab a site content on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4.2

I'm just started to learn about the iOS SDK.

I want to type a URL on a TextField and load a page like in a hidden browser.
And when the page finish the loading I need the HTML, to fill a TableView with the results.

I don't need to download the whole page, just the html text.

Basically I'm writtig a "front-end" to a public web service, I'm goggling for a while and can't find a answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867002/how-to-download-a-web-page-data-in-objective-c-on-iphone

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `NSURLConnection`. See the [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for full details.

Answer (score 1):

NSString can solve your problem:
`[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"google.com"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];`

Comment: why this works to `http://apple.com` but does not work to `http://websro.correios.com.br/sro_bin/txect01$.Inexistente?P_LINGUA=001&P_TIPO=002&P_COD_LIS=EC003071085BR` why?