# How Can I Retrieve the HTML Code for A Webpage In Swift

Tags: swift

Using Swift, how can I retrieve the HTML Code of a webpage. I have read up on http requests but I cannot figure out how to implement them to fetch the HTML code. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: The similar question suggested does not seem to have a working solution.

Comment: This was solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016142/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-swift

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick: (adapted from the objective-c in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867002/how-to-download-a-web-page-data-in-objective-c-on-iphone))

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com")
var error: NSError?
let html = NSString(contentsOfURL: url!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error)

if (error != nil) {
    println("whoops, something went wrong")
} else {
    println(html!)
}
```

Comment: Whenever I enter an url such as https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl its says "whoops, something went wrong"

Comment: The error I get is: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 256.)" UserInfo=0x7d26e9b0 {NSURL=https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl})

Comment: that seems to be related to SSL?

Comment: is there any way to get html source converted to a string instead NSString?

Comment: @slash89mf just cast it to string with `as String`.